# I can use the value of a variable as a variable name?

Tags: assembly, 68000

I was thinking (within the limits of my knowledge), that to load values with different lengths (but always ending with 0), it would be convenient if I could use the value of a variable as a variable name. For example, in:

`lea sc1, a2`

if I could use the suffix sc combined with the value of d0 instead of sc1, I could easily scroll through the data section.
Is there a way to do this?

example:

```
     move.w #4,d0    ; loop 5 times

loop
     lea    sc1,a2
     ; .... some code
     dbf    d0,loop

     clr    -(a7)        ; end
     trap   #1

   section data

sc1  dc.b 15,15,"Space",0
sc2  dc.b 10,4,"F1",0
sc3  dc.b 10,9,"F2",0
sc4  dc.b 10,44,"F9",0
sc5  dc.b 10,49,"F10",0
```

Comment: In almost every language where you think you want to do this, the better solution is "use an array".  In this case, perhaps an array of pointers.

Comment: In this instance, it's pretty clearly impossible: the label names are only used by the assembler and do not exist at runtime.

Comment: Asm symbol names work the same way C global variable names work.  There's no runtime name resolution.  If you want that, you need a dictionary data structure.  There is no perl `eval` type of thing, because that's not how CPUs work, at all.  Or to map an integer to a string, a simple array.

Comment: You can pad zeros at the end of each entry to make them the same length (if no entry is longer than `15,15,"Space",0` 8 bytes per entry would suffice and you could conveniently `addq.l #8,a2` after each iteration. Alternatively, have another table with (relative) offsets to the actual data.

Comment: It's a similar problem with trying to iterate through the `Dn` registers. You can't do that directly either, so you have to store their values in memory and loop through said memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to actually do that. Those "sc1","sc2", etc. are just a convenience for the programmer when writing the code. The assembler converts them to memory addresses once the code is assembled. To use the 68000's vector table as an example:

```
.org 0
initial_stack_pointer:
dc.l $FFFFFFFE
reset:
dc.l $00000400   ;your code begins at this address
```

Once the program is assembled, the labels are destroyed, and any reference to `reset` in your code becomes the constant number 4 (since we started at 0 and each `dc.l` takes up four bytes of space.)

However, all is not lost. There is a little trick you can use to make this happen.
If you make a separate table of pointers to each of those strings, you can iterate through them more easily without having to deal with a bunch of padding.

```
     move.w #4,d0    ; loop 5 times
     lea    sc_table,a2
loop
     move.l (a2),a1      ;get the address of the string into a1
     move.b (a1)+,D2     ;load the first 15 in 15,15,"Space",0 into D2
     ;then you'd probably want to have an inner loop that repeats this 
     ;until the terminator is reached.
     
     ; .... some code
     adda.l #4,a2        ;next sc
     dbf    d0,loop

     clr    -(a7)        ; end
     trap   #1

   section data

sc_table:
dc.l sc1
dc.l sc2
dc.l sc3
dc.l sc4
dc.l sc5

sc1  dc.b 15,15,"Space",0
sc2  dc.b 10,4,"F1",0
sc3  dc.b 10,9,"F2",0
sc4  dc.b 10,44,"F9",0
sc5  dc.b 10,49,"F10",0
.align 2
```

This technique can be a bit confusing because you have to dereference twice, but once you get the hang of it, string lists will be much easier to manage. It's very common to use a similar technique in video games for loading animations. You'd have a table of pointers to each frame of animation, and use a timer variable (which is incremented each frame) as an index into that table.